# Bug on Safari Mobile iOS 8.2 Copying whole page causes page to reload and doesn't work

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, meta, mobile-safari

Here's how to reproduce. Go to Stack Overflow. Find a question that has some action on it (I've noticed that very short questions/answers work fine). Highlight the whole page. Tap copy. Safari puts a little banner at the top that says something like "there was a problem, this page was reloaded". It works fine in Chrome mobile.

BTW, I'm using the iPad Air 2. I have not tested it on other devices. But it was working with iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: I have experienced this same bug, or similar bug, on a rails site I am working on.  When I click a delete icon, the controller action leads back to the same page, but now different content should be displayed.  This works sometimes, breaks sometimes.  You have to actually press reload to see the correct content on the page.  I am using an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.2.   Everything works fine on mobile Chrome and on desktop.  Very frustrating.